# bezier curve to draw area under the code with wpf dynamic data display

Tags: wpf, charts, bezier, dynamic-data-display

I have a program that creates a chart with dynamicdatadisplay. I need to fill the specified area under the curve (not the whole curve, just a part, for example if i have a sinus from 0 to 1 in x axis, just the area under the curve that corresponds between 0.2 and 0.5 in the x-axis).

Does anyone has any idea how to do this? I have been thinking, maybe I could do a Bezier curve with the Y values that corresponds to this segment of the sinus curve and fill in it, but I don't get the commands to draw something.

```
<d3:ViewportPolyBezierCurve x:Name="vpbc" BuildBezierPoints="True" BezierPoints="0.1,1,0.3,0.4,5,0.5" Fill="Red"></d3:ViewportPolyBezierCurve>
```

Does anyone know how to draw a beziercurve with dynamic data display?

I could also implement a bezier curve with Path Geometry Figure, but then, when I insert that to my plot and I do zoom, the plot changes size, but the bezier curve not!

Any help would be really appreciated!